# Using GPIO to control multiple leds via transistors

Tags: transistors, led, gpio

I'm trying to control 16 LEDS with the GPIO ports of a Raspberry Pi using transistors. All 16 can potentially be illuminated together. I'm trying to figure out if I can use approach B to save PCB space by merging the resistors, or if I must go with A (or they're both wrong?):

Version A:                                                                       Version B:

[image]

If B is possible, does it affect how I calculate the value for R7 (all LEDs being identical)?

Right now I'm using LEDs that peak at 20mA (a bit too bright actually) with 3.3V forward voltage. But I can switch those out for different ratings if necessary.

Comment: Will only one of the LEDs be illuminated at any given time, or will more than one be on simultaneously? How much current will each LED draw? What is the forward voltage of the LEDs?

Comment: 1/ Neither. You have an emitter follower. You should put the LED and resistor in the collector. 2/ B is sub-optimal as the LED's will have different intensity if one or both are on.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson All LEDs might be on simultaneously. I updated the question with the LED details.

Comment: @Oldfart Got it. Will you make an answer of that or should I delete the question because its dumb?

Comment: Don't delete the question as there may be others which have the same (slightly flawed) idea. A real answer would require me a lot longer as then I would have to explain that the solution MIGHT work under certain circumstances but the collector... is better because.... I'll let somebody else have the points :-)

Comment: @Oldfart I think I fixed the collector issue in the diagram so no need to mention that. And frankly, lights changing intensity depending on how many are on is enough for me to dismiss B - and accept such a very short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B is bad because resistor R7 will limit the total current sinked to ground, and that total current will have to be shared among all the LEDs connected to it. Depending on R7's value and the number of LEDs connected to it, the current through the LEDs may not be enough and they won't "turn on", and brightness will be inconsistent (will depend on the number of LEDs "turned on"). Even worse: if you try to select a low value for R7 to overcome this limitation, the current may be far too high when there are only a few LEDs connected, and you may burn them.

Option A is the way to go, as you can limit the LED current individually without any unwanted "interference" from the other ones.

Comment: R7 is meant to have 16 LEDs on it, all potentially on. However I have power supplies up to 5V 6A. You seem to imply that with plenty of current, B is possible. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible but then you might burn some LEDs when only few of them are ON. Answer edited to reflect this fact.

Comment: In option B, if you calculate R7 value so that it can sink 20mA from 16 LEDs, then it must sink 320 mA. But then, when only one LED is ON, the resistor will let that current though it, probably burning it.

Comment: OK I'm almost ready to forget about B but there is one more thing. I saw that I'm going to have to split my LEDs in two (because of rating differences for different colors) which means that R7 will only have 8 LEDs. Now my datasheet says that the maximum ratings are: "DC forward current = 30mA" and "Peak forward current = 200mA (and 150mA for the other color)". Does that leave a window of possible values for R7?

Comment: I’ll recommend passing on B. Even if you don’t go beyond the maximum current rating, you’ll shorten the LEDs life by making them work beyond the recommended 20mA current. You can easily run into thermal problems. It is very unreliable to make them work like that.

Comment: @schmop Another huge problem is that LED's don't have the same forward voltage, the world isn't perfect, so you won't even get the same brightness through all of them. One will hog all the current, and as it heats up it will conduct even better and take all the current and pop. Look at your LED's as one after one goes "pop". - What you COULD do however is go with B and then pulse each LED 1/16th of a time. In other words, count from 0 to 15, if the LED should be on, activate that particular LED with all others off. Go to next LED, activate that particular one for 1/16th of the time and etc.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple LEDs may be on simultaneously then option A is required. Option B allows the LED current to vary by up to 16X, which will either cause the LEDs to be very dim when all are on or possibly damaged when just one is on.

If you want to save board space, replace the NPN transistors with suitable logic-level NMOS transistors and eliminate the base resistors (R1 and R2).

Answer (score -1):

Option b is possible if

1. You chose a resistor that will only let x mA through at most, where X is the nominal max operating current of your led. (Typically 20mA, the 30mA is the absolute max I'm going to blow current.)
2. You chose LEDs that share the same typical forward voltage, i.e. dont mix 1.8v and 3.4v leds.
3. You are okay with the LEDs not appearing at full brightness as more leds share the same resistor. If these LEDs are for illuminating something that may be a problem. If they are for indicating then a much lower forward current is fine. 2 LEDs sharing a resistor set for 20mA will see 10mA, 8 LEDs may see 2.5 mA each.

The leds will be visible down to a fraction of a mA, but that's like a pin prick of visible.  So there is a practical limit to the number you can parallel like this for brightness. You could parallel 4 or 2 with acceptable brightness.

For a one off or a few boards this is okay, you could voltage and brightness match each of your LEDs to reduce any difference you may see. For a commercial project you probably dont want to do this as it can look a bit odd. **Resistor packs** are resistors with a common lead and can help reduce board space if needed. Same thing with transistor packs. Or use SMD. You can get professional boards made for pocket change now.